# How to fix error Laravel Migrations error in provider

Tags: laravel

I have written using package route by model
/{slug}

Code

```
 if (get_prefix(Page::class)) {
        Route::get('/', [PublicController::class, 'index'])->name('public.home');
        Route::get('/{slug}', [PublicController::class, 'get']);
    }
    if (get_prefix(Post::class)) {
        Route::get('/{slug}', [PostController::class, 'get']);
    }
```

provider

```
public function boot(){
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(base_path('platform/packages/page/router/web.php'));
        $this->loadViewsFrom(base_path('platform/packages/page/resources/views/'), 'admin.page');
        //todo
        //load loadMigrations DB
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(base_path('platform/packages/page/database/migrations/'));
        // load language
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(base_path('platform/packages/page/resources/lang'), 'admin.page.lang');
    }
```

When I run migrate I get an error

```
after run php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'setting' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `setting` where `key` = SITE_HOME limit 1)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:801
    797▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    798▕                 );
    799▕             }
    800▕
  ➜ 801▕             throw new QueryException(
    802▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    803▕             );
    804▕         }
    805▕     }
```

I searched for the error and the error occurred in the provider I loaded into the router
Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation{closure}(Object(Page\Providers\BaseProviderService))

Comment: The error states that the setting table is not found

Try including this table in your model

    protected $table = "setting";

Comment: @Ramon Soarez
I know this problem but because I query without mirgate successfully.
I initially installed package
Then I migrated and got an error